# Is multiple linear regression the best analysis choice for a non-experimental design?

Tags: multiple-regression, survey

So my research will be using a between-groups, non-experimental design, collecting data using surveys.

I have two numerical predictor variables, and one predicted variable.

Due to the nature of my research question, my predicted variable can either be categorical (comparing group A to group B), or numerical (each participant scores from 0 - 7 on this variable).

I have read that, because my research is non-experimental, I should steer away from any form of ANOVA and should stick with regression instead. 
Is this the case? And if so, is multiple regression the best way to go?
And if I am using multiple regression, is it better if I score my predicted variable categorically or numerically?

Also - just because I'm wondering - since my research is non-experimental and therefore will only be establishing relationships and not inferring causality - does it matter which way around my predictor/predicted variables are?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Can you give us more detail about the outcome variable?  In particular, what does the "participant score" reflect?  Is it something that is on a scale (e.g. some kind of rating system) or something else?

Comment: Since most forms of ANOVA *are* regression, do you have a more specific understanding of what it means to "steer away" from them and "stick with regression"?  And in terms of the "best way to go," what forms of regression are you implicitly contrasting "multiple regression" to?  Univariate regression would be the obvious reading, but that makes little sense in this context.

Comment: Hey :) So I'm doing a study about binge-watching television, so the outcome variable is binge-watching behaviour. i can either ask participants whether they binge-watch or not (a "yes" group vs a "no" group), or ask how many days in the last 7 they have binge-watched (scoring from 0-7).

Comment: Also, my predictor variables are scores on two separate psychometrics questionnaires (one for general mental wellbeing, and another for addictive personality). So these two would be my predictor variables, and I believe it was multiple linear regression that my tutor told me to look at using.

Comment: wHO TOLD YOU TO USE REGRESSION, NOT ANOVA, BECAUSE THE DESIGN IS "NON-EXPERIMENTAL"?  ANOVA is a special case of regression, so whatever is the arguments against anova, is arguments aganst regression as well .